# Freetagging with location?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, users, location

I want users to be searchable by their location. How do you add a free tagging widget type to a location field. Or, can GMAP/Location recognize every city as a term? Basically, how can users have location terms in their profile.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the location module you'll have a couple of barriers with profiles on D7. I think they are working on a fapi compatible version but it is not ready yet.

There is a D6 module ([html5 user geolocation](http://drupal.org/project/html5_user_geolocation)) which may provide a good starting point.

Given a location (lat long) the [Google maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests) can give you an address.

You can then just pick the administrative level you like and save that as a tag.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Is there any API for Gmap in 7?  I noticed Geo taxonomy in Gmaps for 6.  Could open layers do what I'm trying to do?  The concept I'm tying to accomplish is similar to a dating service where you find people by interests and location.  I just need an API for location that can turn the user inputted location into terms so a basic location search can be enacted upon them.  I'm really trying to stay in 7.

Comment: Sry, I see Google maps API isn't a module.  I guess I'm just wondering how the locations become terms.  Can I give users a permission for freetagging just for Location?

Answer (score 1):

For free-tagging style, cite-based, geographic location of user, I would use a dedicated taxonomy vocabulary. With geographic location information attached to each term in the vocabulary. Taxonomy terms are entities, so like for many other entity types, you an attach fields to them.  So the [Geofield](https://drupal.org/project/geofield) module can be used to attach this information.

With minor coding, it should be possible to provide an implementation of [`hook_taxonomy_term_insert()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.api.php/function/hook_taxonomy_term_insert/7) that automatically add geographic information to newly created cities (ie. term in the dedicated vocabulary) using some geocoding service, and/or the mark them as needing manual review and geocoding. This may even be possible without any coding using the (recent) [Geocoder](https://drupal.org/project/geocoder) module. You can also import cities for your intended audience periodically with the [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) module (but you may need to provide your own mapper for Geofield).

Another option is to directly adds geographic information to either user entities or user profile (using [Profile2](https://drupal.org/project/profile2)). For this, the Geofield module already provide some map-based input widgets, and geocoding through Geocoder.